# c++ Child class Unable to initialize Base class's member variable?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

So this question adds to my previous question about initializing member vector in an initialization list..

Here are my base & derived class definitions...

```
class Base {
public:
    std::vector<int> m_Vector;
}


class Derived : public Base {
    Derived() : m_Vector {1, 2, 3} {}      // ERROR when referring to m_Vector
}
```

When trying to initialize Derived's m_Vector.. I get an error in Visual Studio saying that

```
"m_Vector" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "Derived"
```

Why can't derived class refer to m_Vector in this case..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the data member in the derived class constructor after it has been initialized, but you need to perform the initialization in the base class. For example,

```
class Base 
{
public:
    std::vector<int> m_Vector;
    Base() : m_Vector {1, 2, 3} {} 
};

class Derived : public Base 
{

};
```

This is because the base class (and by extension, all its data members) are initialized before the derived class and any of its members.

If you need to be able to control the initialization values of `Base`'s data members from `Derived`, you can add a suitable constructor to `Base`, and use this in `Derived`:

```
class Base 
{
public:
    std::vector<int> m_Vector;
    Base(const std::vector<int>& v) : m_Vector(v) {}
    Base(std::vector<int>&& v) : m_Vector(std::move(v)) {}
};

class Derived : public Base 
{
public:
  Derived() : Base({1, 2, 3}) {}

};
```

Comment: And what if `base` doesn't know what to values to initialize the vector with, but `derived` does?

Comment: @MooingDuck Then why is `m_Vector` a member of `Base` and not `Derived`? Anyway, `Base` could accept a parameter in its constructor with which to initialize the member. Or, `Derived` constructor could modify the vector in its body - it just can't initialize it in constructor initializer list.

Comment: @user2436815 I added an example showing what you can do.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I rather think it's astoundingly common for any class to have a constructor that takes values to initialize it's internals, that isn't even specific to inheritance.    (Juanchopanza, this code has an unnecessary copy, easily removed in C++03, trivially removed in C++11: `Base(std::vector<int> v) : m_Vector(std::move(v)) {}` or `Base(std::vector<int> v) {m_Vector.swap(v);}`?)

Comment: @MooingDuck I added an rvalue ref constructor, if that's what you were referring to. I think it is OK to keep two overloads here.

Comment: @user2436815 Does this answer your question? If not, please clarify what it is you are asking.